# Flutter- Card elevation without shadow

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to design a my card like this. But when I use elevation property generally it gives a card view with shadow. How to remove shadow from card and make a view like this image.

[image: card]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `shadowColor : Colors.transparent` for it.

```
Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
    elevation: 20,
    shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
    color: Colors.white,
    child : Container()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional named param elevation. Set it zero.

```
elevation: 0,
```

Comment: But by giving elevation 0 the card view don't looks like this